# HTML/CSS - How can I position these nested unordered lists correctly?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, nested-lists

I am looking for some help resolving an issue im having with positioning the following unordered list elements that are contained in a div which has relative positioning:

The html structure of the UL:

```
<div id="accountBox" class="account_settings_box">
    <ul>
        <ul>
            <li class="profileImage">
                <img src="images/profileimage.jpg" alt="Profile Image" />
            </li>
            <li class="profileName">Your name</li>
            <li class="profileEmail">Your email</li>
        </ul>
        <li><a href="">Messages</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Password</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sign out</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and the CSS for this list:

```
.account_settings_box ul ul  {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    outline: 1px solid blue;
}

.account_settings_box ul ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    border: none; /* Reset the border */
}

.profileImage {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    outline: 1px solid purple;
}

.profileName, .profileEmail {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}

.account_settings_box ul ul li:hover {
    outline: 1px solid red;
}

.profileImage img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

I am having difficultly with the embedded ul, i.e, .account_settings_box ul ul element.

The image below shows what it currently looks like.

**I am trying to achieve the follow:**

Have the image floating to the right, and have the "your name" and "your email" positioned to the left of the image (basically where they are currently).

[image: Unordered list screenshot]

Thanks for your help in advance.

Sam :)

Answer (score 0):

Half of your struggles are likely around your first child `<ul>` element nested below the parent one, which should be contained within its own `<li>`:

```
<div id="accountBox" class="account_settings_box">
                            <ul>
                               <li>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="profileImage"><img src="images/profileimage.jpg" alt="Profile Image" /></li>
                                        <li class="profileName">Your name</li>
                                        <li class="profileEmail">Your email</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="">Messages</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Settings</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Password</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Sign out</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

From there, I think you want to update your CSS as follows:

```
.account_settings_box ul  {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    outline: 1px solid blue;
}

.account_settings_box ul li ul { display: block; }

.account_settings_box ul > li {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: none; /* Reset the border */
}

.profileImage {
    float: right;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    outline: 1px solid purple;
}

.profileName, .profileEmail {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}

.account_settings_box ul ul li:hover {
    outline: 1px solid red;
}

.profileImage img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: I tried out your method and it didn't seem to get the right positioning. I am getting close, just gotta persevere. Ill post the solution once I get it.